# NSDate Showing Wrong Day

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am taking an NSDate, and pulling just a 2-digit number, representing the day of the month into an NSString.  One of the dates in question is:

2013-11-30 00:00:00 +0000

I use:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *datefromdate = [formatter2 stringFromDate:articleDate];
NSLog(@"Date%@", datefromdate);
[formatter2 release];
```

but the log comes back

```
29
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably in a negative time zone i.e. GMT minus something. This is why `2013-11-30 00:00:00 +0000 GMT` is on the 29th day when you log it. Set the formatter to GMT and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Set the timezone you want the time date formatter to use. NSDate is the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT and thus has no timezone information in it.

So, this, according to Apple, is going to get complicated needing up to five classes: `NSDateFormatter`, `NSDate`, `NSCalendar`, `NSTimeZone` and finally `NSDateComponents`.

If all you want is the day you can use `NSDateComponents`.

Example:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-11-30 00:00:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [inDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateFromString: %@", date);

NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

// Using date formatter, result is a string
NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[outDateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];
[outDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayString = [outDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date formatter day: %@", dayString);

// Using date components, result is an integer
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone: timezone];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSLog(@"date components day: %i", day);
```

NSLog output:

```
dateFromString: 2013-11-30 00:00:00 +0000
date formatter day: 30
date components day: 30
```

Comment: 100 claps for this answer.
could you tell me what is the magic behind timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT?

Comment: See: Apple documentation: [timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387199-timezoneforsecondsfromgmt).